# Formatting search results displayed in a div

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I would like get some advice on formatting `div` tags.

Currently the `div` tag in my codes will display the results that was performed in a function:

```
document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = searchHTML;
```

and the searchresults will be displayed in the div.

```
<div id="searchresults"></div>
```

Currently the outputs that will displayed will be stacked horizontally.

It looks kind messy as it is difficult to differentiate each output.

I would like to know is there a way to format each of the output. For example each of the outputs will be in a container of their own?

And can each of the container can personalized even more?

Comment: Hard to say without an output example.

Comment: The short answer is: yes, you should have each result in a `div` of its own. Essentially, you'll end up with: `<div id="searchresults"><div class="result">[...]</div><div class="result">[...]</div>[...]</div>` and remember, you can have as many nested elements as needed to present the data in an accessible manner. Go nuts.

Comment: Styling is more a case of preference. The easiest (and probably) only way of styling each result individually is by having each result in their own container.

Comment: Thanks ninty9notout.

Will giv it a try

Answer (score 1):

For each result do the following:

```
// Create div
var resultDiv = document.createElement('div');
resultDiv.innerHTML = result;
resultDiv.className = "resultContainer"; // Add appropriate CSS

// Append result to container
document.getElementById('searchresults').appendChild(resultDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you dynamically generate the divs via javacript? Using a for loop do something like.. for each search result, generate div X with search result X

Answer (score 0):

make sure that "#searchresults" has a width and height and position:relative

and add a css-class also with width and height and float:left to the wrapping container of each searchresult inside the searchHTML

and voila

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can wrap the output in a tag, e.g. a `<div>` to make the output flow vertically. Then you can use CSS to style the content in your `searchresults` panel:

```
document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = "<div class='line'>" + searchHTML + "</div>";

#searchresults .line {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks defrost.

will give it a try